# Number of binary matrices with all 1's connected

Tags: algorithms, graphs

> What's the best/optimal known method/algorithm known that can be used
>   to calculate the number of binary $M_{m,n}$ matrices for given $n,m$, whose $1$'s are all connected?
>
> Or equivalently, to calculate the number of connected induced subgraphs of a grid graph.

I'm aware of the computed values so far listed on [$(n,m)$ OEIS table](http://oeis.org/A287151), and also that formulas are known for the [$(1,n)$](http://oeis.org/A000217),[$(2,n)$](http://oeis.org/A059020),[$(3,n)$](http://oeis.org/A059021) cases, and supposedly an empirical generating function for [$(4,n)$](http://oeis.org/A059524).

I assume those were derived from the computed data.

I'm interested to know what algorithm was used (or what's the best known option that could've been used) to compute the larger terms in the [linked table](http://oeis.org/A287151/b287151.txt), and how effective/complex it was?

Comment: This question is closely related to the following "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914492/how-can-one-enumerate-connected-subgraphs-of-the-square-grid-graph" which has received an answer. It would seem (Disclaimer: I am merely summarising the answer to the linked question) that this problem is closely related to computing the number of $k$-polykings (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polyomino)